# PostgresSQL avoid duplicates after left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I am a newbie to SQL.
I have 2 tables,
Table 1 - fac_vis with columns `sending_id` and `receiving_id`.
Table 2 - f_lab with columns `fac_id`, `id`, `name`

What I want to achieve is, I have a `fac_id`. Using that id I want to fetch rows in `fac_vis` where column `sending_id` is equal to id and get associated `receiving_id`.

Then go to f_lab table and fetch all results for fetched `sending_id` and `receiving_id`

Tried above using following query

```
select * from public.fac_vis fv
left join f_lab fl on fl.fac_id = fv.sending_id or fl.fac_id = fv.receiving_id
where fv.sending_facility_id = '1'
```

Issue is there are 2 results for the `where` clause and after left join it is fetching twice for an id.

How can I remove the duplicates or fetch for a particular id once.
Here is my fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4TCE1mCLeWxx8x1ihUjBYD/0

Comment: It's not duplicating anything, it's doing exactly what you asked it.   I would guess the `OR` piece of your join clause is causing what you think are dupes.

Comment: Yes it is working fine. But how would I modify the query to get only one result from second table?

Comment: It depends on which one you need, for the sender or for the receiver

Comment: I need for both 

Comment: Please show your desired result.

Comment: Yes, the fiddle  is showing your actual result, not your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM fac_vis fv
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (fac_id) fac_id, id, name
    FROM f_lab
) fl ON fl.fac_id = fv.sending_id OR fl.fac_id = fv.receiving_id
WHERE fv.sending_id = '1';

    SELECT DISTINCT ON (fac_id) fac_id, id, name
    FROM f_lab
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**